# fnmatch working inconsistently in different scripts

Tags: python, file-handling

I am working on a python script that will write input files for an analysis program I use. One of the steps is to take a list of filenames and search the input directory for them, open them, and get some information out of them. I wrote the following using `os.walk` and `fnmatch` in a test-script that has the directory of interest hard-coded in, and it worked just fine:

```
for locus in loci_select: # for each locus we'll include
    print("Finding file " + locus)
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('../phylip_wigeon_mid1_names'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, locus): # look in the input directory
            print("Found file for locus " + locus + " in set")
            loci_file = open(os.path.join('../phylip_wigeon_mid1_names/', filename))
            with loci_file as f:
                for i, l in enumerate(f):
                    pass
             count = (i) * 0.5 # how many individuals present
             print(filename + "has sequences for " + str(count) + " individuals")
```

...and so on (the other bits all work, so I'll spare you).

As soon as I put this into the larger script and switch out the directory names for input arguments, though, it seems to stop working between the third and fourth lines, despite being nearly identical:

```
    for locus in use_loci: # for each locus we'll include
        log.info("Finding file " + locus)
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(args.input_dir):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, locus): # look in the input directory
                 log.info("Found file for locus " + locus + " in set")
                 loci_file = open(os.path.join(args.input_dir, filename))
                 with loci_file as f:
                     for i, l in enumerate(f):
                        pass
                 count = (i) * 0.5 # how many individuals present
                 log.info(filename + "has sequences for " + str(count) + " individuals")
```

I've tested it with temporary print statements between the suspected lines, and it seems like they are the culprits, since my screen output looks like:

```
2015-11-17 15:53:20,505 - write_ima2p_input_file - INFO - Getting selected loci for analysis
2015-11-17 15:53:20,505 - write_ima2p_input_file - INFO - Finding file uce-7999_wigeon_mid1_contigs.phy

2015-11-17 15:53:20,629 - write_ima2p_input_file - INFO - Finding file uce-4686_wigeon_mid1_contigs.phy

 2015-11-17 15:53:20,647 - write_ima2p_input_file - INFO - Finding file uce-5012_wigeon_mid1_contigs.phy
```

...and so on.

I've tried switching out to `glob`, as well as simple things like rearranging where this section falls in my larger code, but nothing is working. Any insight would be much appreciated!